# Receive error when deploy to GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, github-pages, npm-build

I'm deploy react app to git hub pages and receive error. File sizes after gzip:

```
68.67 KB  build\static\js\2.c2c334ae.chunk.js
 2.98 KB  build\static\js\main.8a72b1a2.chunk.js
  774 B   build\static\js\runtime~main.8f8a00a4.js
```

The project was built assuming it is hosted at `/sort-customers-list/`.
You can control this with the homepage field in your `package.json`.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
To publish it at https://sejob.github.io/sort-customers-list,
run: npm run deploy

Find out more about deployment here:

```
sort-customers-list@0.1.0 deploy 
C:\Users\SeJo\Documents\Code\DEV_HW\sort-customers-list
gh-pages -d build
```

The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sort-customers-list@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sort-customers-list@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    
C:\Users\SeJo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-01T12_09_52_445Z-debug.log
```

Comment: First answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314779/trying-to-deploy-my-react-app-with-gh-pages-but-got-this-error-message-the-fi   really helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs in the new version of GitHub pages. Just use this command to install the previous version of GitHub pages:

```
npm install gh-pages@2.0.1
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 4):

I also had this same problem on a fresh install of `create-react-app`. I have no idea what the problem was, but I did the following:

1. Downgrade `gh-pages` from `2.1.0` to `2.0.1`
2. Instead of running `npm run deploy`, manually run `npm run build` then `gh-pages -d build` from the commandline.

At first, I'd get the same error in the commandline, even after checking that the version was downgraded to `2.0.1`, but for some reason it worked after manually creating the `gh-pages` branch and pushing some files into it. As of now, `npm run deploy` throws the error but at least `gh-pages -d build` from the console works.

Answer (score 1):

**INSTALL/REINSTALL GIT
Update NPM
Reopen EDITOR**

this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

use version 2.0.1

```
npm i gh-pages@2.0.1
```