# gh-pages -d build gives Error "file" argument must be a non-empty string

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I included all the steps for deploying my create react app on github.
snippet of my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",`enter code here`
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "homepage": "http://myName.github.io/create-react-wars",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
},
```

this is the error i am getting

```sh
gh-pages -d build
```

```sh
"file" argument must be a non-empty string
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-star-wars@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-star-wars@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jishu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-02T17_13_43_435Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Got the same issue; this answer solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315930/11879312

"Seems like a bug in gh-pages 2.1. I solved mine by downgrading gh-pages to version 2.0: yarn add gh-pages@2.0 -D or npm install gh-pages@2.0 --dev."

Comment: hi Justin, thanks for the reply. now my app deployed perfectly. but when i got to my github deployed path homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp" i am getting 404 error for all my build files.

Comment: Here's what I did when I got this problem. First, I would put the "homepage" entry outside the "script" block like so: ... "homepage": "myName.github.io/create-react-wars", "scripts": { ... }, ... Second, make sure that your "homepage" has the exact same name of your code repo. Eg. if your repo name is "create-react-wars", then your "homepage" should be "myName.github.io/create-react-wars" <-- Note the https may be important. –

Comment: hi Justin, still no luck. i am getting 404 error for my build files like - GET https://jishanali123.github.io/static/css/2.22a7d4ef.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
manifest.json:1 GET https://jishanali123.github.io/manifest.json 404

Answer (score 0):

I think the command is like this.

```sh
gatsby -d public -b master
```

Where public is the folder you want to push and master is the branch you want to push to.
Please run your build before this