# Problem while deploying `create-react-app` on github using `gh-pages`

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages, create-react-app

I am getting below error while deploying an app created using `create-react-app` on  github using `gh-pages`.

```
"file" argument must be a non-empty string
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-text-echo@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-text-echo@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have referred [this link](https://medium.com/@_mariacheline/deploy-create-react-app-project-to-github-pages-2eb6deda5b89) and [this one](https://reactgo.com/deploy-react-app-github-pages/).

Can anyone help me to figure out what exactly is the problem?

My github project link is - https://github.com/aagjalpankaj/react-text-echo

My package.json file is - https://github.com/aagjalpankaj/react-text-echo/blob/master/package.json

Comment: show your `package.json`

Comment: @DennisVash- https://github.com/aagjalpankaj/react-text-echo/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a bug in `gh-pages 2.1.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315930/7882470) downgrade `gh-pages` to version `2.0`:

```sh
npm install gh-pages@2.0 --dev.
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Deployed successfully - [https://aagjalpankaj.github.io/react-text-echo/](https://aagjalpankaj.github.io/react-text-echo/)